# Namespacing for seeders

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to see what I'm doing wrong for my seed file to not work with my namespacing properly and wanted to see if someone can spot what's not working in this code.

> Error: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App\Models\Eloquent' not found in
>   /Users/me/Repositories/personal/project/app/models/Event.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

class Event extends Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = [];

    /**
    * The database table used by the model.
    *
    * @var string
    */
    protected $table = 'events';
}
```

```
<?php

use App\Models\Event;

// Composer: "fzaninotto/faker": "v1.3.0"
use Faker\Factory as Faker;

class EventsTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        $faker = Faker::create();

        foreach(range(1, 100) as $index)
        {
            Event::create([

            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any error or unexpected result you get?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to include it. Its in the post now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to point to `Eloquent` in the root namespace instead of `Eloquent` inside `App\Models` (which doesn't exist)

To do that either reference id with a backslash:

```
class Event extends \Eloquent {
```

or add a `use` statement:

```
use Eloquent

class Event extends Eloquent {
```